# Delete NetCDF attributes with CDO

Tags: netcdf, cdo-climate, nco

How can I use the CDO `delete` operator to remove variable-specific and/or global attributes of a NetCDF?

As far as I understand from the help pages of the operator, I should provide a comma-separated list of attributes, keyed by `param`, but:

```
$ cdo delete,param="pr@missing_value,Title" ifile.nc ofile.n
cdo    delete (Warning): Parameter >pr:missing_value< not found!
cdo    delete (Warning): Parameter >Title< not found!
```

---

NOTE: this is the list of attributes of my test file:

```
$ cdo showattribute ifile.nc
pr:
   long_name = "precipitation"
   units = "mm"
   missing_value = -999
Global:
   Conventions = "CF-1.5" 
   Title = "Ninja Title"
   Created on = "Wed Aug 25 03:29:12 2021"
```

---

<sub>Using `CDO version 1.9.9`</sub>

Answer (score 3):

Actually I usually find nco is much more appropriate for this kind of task.

You can delete the attribute of the variable using `ncatted`

```
ncatted -a att_nm,var_nm,mode,att_type,att_val
```

so in your case it would be

```
ncatted -O -a missing_value,pr,d,, file.nc
```

d is for "delete", [see this page for usage](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ncatted)

To delete the global attribute, [using this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59729526/how-to-edit-global-attributes-in-netcdf-file-with-nco), you would instead write

```
ncatted -O -a title,global,d,, file.nc
```

Hint: you can also add the -h option to prevent additions to the netcdf history global attribute